# How do I reshape or pivot a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to reshape a DataFrame in Pandas but not sure how to go about it. Here's  what I'm starting with:

```
Phase Weight Value  CF
AA   heavy    0.28  1.0
AB   light    3.26  1.0
BX   med      0.77  1.0
XY   x light -0.01  1.0
AA   heavy    0.49  1.5
AB   light    5.10  1.5
BX   med      2.16  1.5
XY   x light  0.98  1.5
AA   heavy    2.48  2.0
AB   light   11.70  2.0
BX   med      5.81  2.0
XY   x light  3.46  2.0
```

I would like to reshape to this:

```
Phase       Weight  1.0     1.5     2.0
AA          heavy   0.28    0.49    2.48
AB          light   3.26    5.10    11.70
BX          med     0.77    2.16    5.81
XY        x light  -0.01    0.98    3.46
```

So column names are now the values that were in CF and the intersection of the row and columns in the new table are the values that were in the value column in the original table.

I know I can do it with the Phase column as an index like so:

```
df.pivot(index='Phase', columns='CF', values='Value)
```

But then I miss the weight column.I tried this but I'm getting an error

```
df.pivot(index='Phase', columns=['Weight','CF'], values='Value')
```

Is there a way to do this with a single statement ? If not, what is the best way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `pd.pivot_table` which can take multiple names as arguments to index/column parameters.  I also think you want Weight on the index (which makes it a column in the output) rather than on columns (which turns the distinct values into columns).

```
In [27]: df.pivot_table(index=['Phase','Weight'], columns='CF', values='Value').reset_index()
Out[27]: 
CF Phase   Weight   1.0   1.5    2.0
0     AA    heavy  0.28  0.49   2.48
1     AB    light  3.26  5.10  11.70
2     BX      med  0.77  2.16   5.81
3     XY  x light -0.01  0.98   3.46
```

Edit:

On your other question, the `.columns` of a DataFrame are an Index (just like on the rows), and have a `.name` in addition to the actual values.  As far as I'm aware, it's generally only used for display purposes.

```
In [74]: df.columns
Out[74]: Index([u'Phase', u'Weight', 1.0, 1.5, 2.0], dtype='object')

In [75]: df.columns.name
Out[75]: 'CF'

In [76]: df.columns.values
Out[76]: array(['Phase', 'Weight', 1.0, 1.5, 2.0], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I keep getting a type error :

    TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Comment: Either upgrade to 0.14 (index will be the prospective name), or change `index` to `rows`.  See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecations

Comment: Is there a way to drop the "CF" text in the output. It is confusing to  someone reading that output that is not familiar with DataFrames. CF looks like a column with values 0:3 but the real values for CF are 1.0, 1.5, 2.0.

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked great ! 

Just one question though. Why does it work ? I would think it would set all column names to ''. Not just the CF. My column names are 1,1.5,2,2.5....etc. Why wouldn't it set all those to '' ?

Not complaining at all about the solution. Just a newbie trying to understand.